# need help installing ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm installing 1.87.

I got ruby installed and ruby gems

then I tried this from the command prompt: gem install rails

and it gave me this error: http://screencast.com/t/wmBr2b1vC5I

I got the devkit like it suggested and put it in a directory on my desktop but when I went to github for instructions I got lost.

Can someone help guide me step by step? I'm used to PHP and MySQL using WAMP so running things from the command line is new to me.

Comment: I've installed ruby via DevKit without any problem on Windows Vista. Where did you get lost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of gems require native code to be built and linked to as they're being installed.  Unfortunately, Windows does not provide any compiling and linking tools, so you have to take one of several routes to enable building native code in Ruby gems.

I've always used Cygwin in the past to accomplish this, but there's also the Ruby Installer which may benefit you more.

Ruby Installer: http://rubyinstaller.org/

You'll probably need to remove your current Ruby install before running the installer, but it should give you everything you need to make installing Rails possible.

If you don't want to use the full installer, you can download "Development Kit", which is part of the installer, to just add the necessary build tools to your command-line environment.

Development Kit: https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

Comment: thanks Ryan. I installed a newer version of Ruby and that did the trick. 1.92 is the way to go. I still had a problem with the missing dll file but i found it online and copied and pasted it into the bin folder of ruby. Hopefully that does the trick.